# Debug mock httpbackend requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, angular-file-upload

I have a situation where there are many mocked http requests. While working on angular upload, something fishy happening in my case. It is always throwing `status:200 success` and `html complete body response`.

Below is my angular upload code:

```
function fileUploadController(FileUploader) {
    /* jshint validthis: true */
    let vm = this;
    vm.type = this.type;
    vm.clientId = this.client;

    let uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'http://localhost:8001/prom-scenario-config/files?clientId=' + vm.clientId,
        data: {type: vm.type}
    });

    vm.uploads = {uploader};
    vm.upload = upload;
    vm.uploads.uploader.queue = [];

    vm.uploads.uploader.onCompleteItem = function (item, response) {
        let type = item.uploader.data.type;
        console.log('response => ', response);
    };
 }
```

mock of httpbackend code looks like this:

```
$httpBackend.whenPOST(new RegExp('http://localhost:8001/prom-scenario-config/files\\?clientId=([a-zA-Z0-9-])$$'))
  .respond(function () {
   return [200, 'foo'];
});
```

But there is no affect on this.

Is there any error in my regex code in constructing? 
With or without having the mock code. Still the response i am receiving is 200.

There are so many mock requests, i am facing difficulty in identifying which request is being called.

Is there any tricky way to identify which regex call is called? Or enforce my request to mock?

Below is the reference for status and response FYI.

[image][image]

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What is it 'throwing'? What is the exact error? What is FileUploader? Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Problem is from success not with error. Not able to call my mock request and has impact on my code. PFA for the screenshots recently added

Comment: Again, all relevant code should be posted. It's not obvious that FileUploader calls $http.post. At the current point you're the only person who has a chance to figure out what's wrong. The screenshot doesn't have .../upload/... url.

Comment: Due to security issues, i thought of posting like test/upload. Changed it now. Please check

Comment: I am the only responsible person to debug which i am trying to figure out from 2 days without any luck.

Comment: Then please, don't make the task harder for the possible answerers and provide all relevant code. FileUploader is crucial here and it's not included.

Comment: Fileuploader is an angular-file-upload injection dependency. Not custom service

Comment: That's even more important. From what I see, it uses XHR directly, not $http, so it cannot be mocked with $httpBackend. In unit tests you should mock everything but tested unit. It is FileUpload that should be mocked, not http request.

Comment: Moreover,  `clientId=([a-zA-Z0-9-])` matches only ids consisting of a single character, which isn't true. That's why it is a terrible idea to provide regexps instead of hard-coded expectations. A tester cannot afford to be lazy... who will test a tester?

Comment: Yes, i rely on an `id` as a response. And yeah, you are correct and i verified. They are relying on xhr: https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/dist/angular-file-upload.js#L724. So, how to handle this?

Comment: Just don't use real FileUpload . This is how unit testing is done. What you're trying to do is integration/functional test, and it is totally ineffective here, considering that you cannot unambiguously identify the problem (this is the goal of any test).

Comment: I'll test and accept the answer later. Thanks once again @estus

Answer (score 1):

Unit test suppose that a unit is tested in isolation. Any other thing which is not a tested unit, i.e. a controller should be mocked, especially third-party units.

Considering that it is tested with Jasmine, `FileUpload` service should be stubbed:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  // a spy should be created inside beforeEach to be fresh every time
  module('app', { FileUpload: jasmine.createSpy() });
});
```

And then controller is tested line by line like:

```
it('...', inject(($controller, FileUpload) => {

  const ctrl = $controller('fileUploadController');
  ...
  expect(FileUpload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(FileUpload).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ url: '...', type: {...} });

  // called with new
  const fileUpload = FileUpload.calls.first().object;
  expect(fileUpload instanceof FileUpload).toBe(true);

  expect(ctrl.fileUpload).toBe(fileUpload);
  expect(fileUpload.onCompleteItem).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
  expect(fileUpload.queue).toEqual([]);
  ...
}));
```

In the code above `clientId=([a-zA-Z0-9-])` regexp part matches only ids consisting of a single character, which isn't true. That's why it is preferable to hard-code values in unit tests, human errors are easier to spot and detect. It's not possible to unambiguously identify the problem when the tests are too loose, this results in wasted time.